# JavaScript Regular expression function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression is not working as expected.Please suggest other way to validate this regular expression in javascript.

```
var patt = new RegExp('^(PK\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16})|(\d{9,20})$');
patt.test('PK12FKIE1234567890123456');
```

Comment: PK12FKIE1234567890123456 or 123456789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put both patterns inside a single group so that the anchors should apply to both.

```
var patt = /^(?:(PK\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{16})|(\d{9,20}))$/;
```

Comment: This is not working for PK12FKIE1234567890123456

Comment: really? https://regex101.com/r/rQ5jC2/2

Comment: thanks it is working